# oddsratio function

Tags: r

How is the `oddsratio` function in R (from the `epitools` package, but I have the same problem with odds.ratio from `questionr` package) calculating the odds ratio? If I do the calculation manually I get a different result. Also, If I input a 2x3 matrix in `oddsratio` for example, I get a 2x3 vector in return. Which odds ratios are those?

For example, if I create a 2X2 matrix `m` and calculate the odds ratio manually and compare it to the results of `oddsratio`:

```r
m = matrix(c(1,6,3,1), ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
odds_rati_manual = ((1/4)/(3/4))/((6/7)/(1/7)) ## = 1/18 = 0.0556
oddsratio(m)$measure = 0.085075
```

why are the two different?

Also, if I input a matrix with 3 rows:

```r
m = matrix(c(1,6,3,1,4,8), ncol = 2, nrow = 3)
oddsratio(m)$measure
```

I get an output with three rows. Is that the odds ratio of the odds from the first row to all the other rows?

Comment: *"how is the ... function calculating the ..."* is almost always best-informed by reading the source of the function(s). Type just `oddsratio` or `odds.ratio` on the console (no parens, no arguments), and look at the source. Or you can look in repos for the source code: [`epitools::oddsratio`](https://github.com/cran/epitools/blob/master/R/oddsratio.R) (technically on CRAN's git repo) and [`questionr::odds.ratio`](https://github.com/juba/questionr/blob/master/R/odds.ratio.R) (its own source repo).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your arithmetic. You are calculating the sample odds ratio, which is the unconditional MLE of the odds ratio. Internally, `epitools::oddsratio` uses `stats::fisher.test` which calculates the conditional MLE using the hypergeometric distribution. I haven't treated myself to a read through the literature to figure out the maths behind this, but it seems to boil down to providing conservative estimates where the numbers in your table are small. For example, `oddsratio(m * 1000)` will give you the same results as working out the odds ratio for m * 1000 by hand

Answer (score 3):

`oddsratio` supports 4 methods.

```
library(epitools)

args(oddsratio)
## function (x, y = NULL, method = c("midp", "fisher", "wald", "small"), 
##     conf.level = 0.95, rev = c("neither", "rows", "columns", 
##         "both"), correction = FALSE, verbose = FALSE)
```

Try `method = "wald"` :

```
m <- matrix(c(1,6,3,1), ncol = 2, nrow = 2)

((1/4)/(3/4))/((6/7)/(1/7))
## [1] 0.05555556

oddsratio(m, method = "wald")$measure
##           odds ratio with 95% C.I.
## Predictor    estimate     lower    upper
##   Exposed1 1.00000000        NA       NA
##   Exposed2 0.05555556 0.0025053 1.231956 <----------
## Warning message:
## In chisq.test(xx, correct = correction) :
##   Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

### 3 rows

Regarding the example with 3 rows each odds ratio is based on the first row and one other row.  Compare these:

```
library(epitools)
m3 <- matrix(c(1,6,3,1,4,8), ncol = 2, nrow = 3)

oddsratio(m3)$measure
##           odds ratio with 95% C.I.
## Predictor  estimate      lower     upper
##   Exposed1 1.000000         NA        NA
##   Exposed2 0.690062 0.01478853  32.24304 <----- compare rows 1 & 2
##   Exposed3 2.449511 0.05171633 115.75523 <----- compare rows 1 & 3

oddsratio(m3[-3, ])$measure
##           odds ratio with 95% C.I.
## Predictor  estimate      lower    upper
##   Exposed1 1.000000         NA       NA
##   Exposed2 0.690062 0.01478853 32.24304 <----- compare rows 1 & 2

oddsratio(m3[-2, ])$measure
##           odds ratio with 95% C.I.
## Predictor  estimate      lower    upper
##   Exposed1 1.000000         NA       NA
##   Exposed2 2.449511 0.05171633 115.7552 <----- compare rows 1 & 3
```